# Communication between scripts is not working,

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a mechanic that if you shoot at a specific object it adds ammo, but I tried a lot of things and ammo is not being added when it collides with the object.

**Here is the code:**

```
public GlobalAmmo ammo;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ammo"))
    {
        ammo.ammo += 3;
    }
}
```

Edit: sorry!
I already put this code and I put in the images that the "if" is working, so I don't understand why this is not working because the ammo decrease correctly.
[image]

I think it must be a very silly mistake, I'm actually doing this project to test everything I'm learning

```
if (collision.transform.tag == "Ammo")
    {
        print("Hit!");
        ammo.ammo += 3;
    }
```

Comment: First, try to debug by putting some Debug.Log instructions in some parts of your algorithm, to check whether your code in the `if` blocks is actually executed or not. Second, please help ourselves (and yourself!) to better understand the problem by giving some information so we could reproduce it. For instance, what objects did you set up on your scene? Is the script you showed currently attached to the player ?

Comment: At least one of the two objects colliding needs to have a rigidbody, maybe that's what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. 
Since the debug console shows the "Hit!" as per your screenshot, what I think is that you are not changing the `ammo` of the correct object. How do you initialize your `public GlobalAmmo ammo`? Are you sure that it is the same **instance** that is used for decreasing the ammo? Or do you have somehow 2 diffferent instances of script `GlobalAmmo` used?

Comment: Phrased in a different way: Is that a script you dragged-dropped over 2 different game objects?

Comment: @Pac0 Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh thanks I think that the problem was that I made a prefab of a empty object (with the script of the GlobalAmmo)  to put on the bullet prefab, but the gun have the original empty object , so I made a prefab of the gun to acces to the same script. It was a very silly mistake but thaanx

Comment: @Pac0 Can I give you points or something similar? hahaha it was vey helpful you commentary.

Comment: Glad to help! I wrote a "proper" answer. You will be able to upvote it when you reach 15 reputation, but you can still click on accept in the mean-time ;).

Answer (score 1):

Does the shooting itself work?

Try to write:

```
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ammo"))
{
    Debug.Log("Work");
    ammo.ammo += 3;
}
```

If you do not write "Work" on the console, then you have an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Since your debugging shows that the `if` is properly executed, I see one main possibility (an easy mistake to make when not used to Unity).

Is that a script you dragged-dropped over 2 different game objects?

You are probably not modifying the proper *instance* of the `GlobalAmmo` class (script) . There might be two (or more) `GlobalAmmo`.

Instead you should refer to only one instance, which is the "source of truth".

For instance, during Init the `public GlobalAmmo ammo;` should be initialized by fetching the proper script instance if it is on another object etc.

As per your comments, it seems you figured it out! Feel free to add more details if this is not the case.